$C(X, A) \otimes C(X, B) \cong C(X, A \otimes B)$?
Consider the category $\mathsf{Ab}$ of abelian groups and $\mathsf{TopAb}$ of topological abelian groups. Given a topological space $X$ and a topological abelian group $A$, define the abelian group $C(X, A) = \{f: X \to A \mid f \text{ continuous}\}$ with pointwise addition. Does the functor $C(X, -): \mathsf{TopAb} \to \mathsf{Ab}, A \mapsto C(X, A)$ preserve tensor products? Concretely, given topological abelian groups $A$ and $B$, do we have $C(X, A) \otimes C(X, B) \cong C(X, A \otimes B)$?
The motivation is this: In condensed mathematics, we define condensed abelian groups, which are sheafs of abelian groups on the site $\mathsf{Prof}$ of profinite sets. We have a faithful functor $F: \mathsf{TopAb} \to \mathsf{CondAb}, A \mapsto (X \mapsto C(X, A))$. We then define the tensor products of the condensed abelian groups $A$ and $B$ as the sheafification of the presheaf $X \mapsto A(X) \otimes B(X)$. The question is: Why is this a reasonable definition? Concretely, given topological abelian groups $A$ and $B$, why do we have $C(X, A) \otimes C(X, B) \cong C(X, A \otimes B)$?

What functor $C(X, {{-}})$ are you asking about?

@BenSteffan Is $C(X, -): \mathsf{TopAb} \to \mathsf{Ab}, A \mapsto C(X, A)$ not clear?

No, because you don't say what $C(X, A)$ is. (Graded sum over) singular chains of some space $X$ with coefficients in $A$? :)

@BenSteffan Thanks, I've added the definition to the question.

Do you really expect this isomorphism? If everything has the discrete topology and $X$ has two points, then $C(X,A)\otimes C(X,B)$ is the direct sum of four copies of $A\otimes B$, but $C(X,A\otimes B)$ is the direct sum of two copies of $A\otimes B$.

How do you make $A\otimes B$ a topological group?

@Jochen Good question, actually. I don't know.

You define the tensor product of condensed abelian groups like this for the same reason you do it this way in any category of sheaves of abelian groups: it gives the tensor product the expected universal property with regards to bilinear maps, just like the tensor product on abelian groups: for any three condensed abelian groups $A$, $B$ and $C$, bilinear maps $A\times B\to C$ correspond bijectively to linear maps $A\otimes B\to C$. This is a good exercise in universal properties of tensor products and sheafification.
You cannot expect the inclusion $\mathsf{TopAb}\hookrightarrow\mathsf{CondAb}$ to preserve the tensor product strictly, because the ambient category in which your topologicał abelian groups lie becomes larger and hence it means a different thing to satisfy the universal property that we want. Jeremy Rickard gave a counterexample in the comments. Instead of being strongly monoidal, the functor $\mathsf{TopAb}\hookrightarrow\mathsf{CondAb}$ is lax monodial: there is a map $C(X,A)\otimes C(X,B)\to C(X,A\otimes B)$ (described below) that is natural in everything and satisfies some nice properties listed at the definition of a lax monoidal functor, and you have a similar map between units of the monoidal structures. Having a lax monoidal functor still means the two tensor products are closely related, and is "good enough" in many practical situations.
The first map witnessing lax monoidality looks like this: by the universal property, it suffices to build a bilinear map $C(X,A)\times C(X,B)\to C(X,A\otimes B)$ that is natural in everything, and for this we send a pair $(f\colon X \to A, g\colon X\to B)$ to the composite $X\xrightarrow{(f,g)}A\times B\xrightarrow{\otimes}A\otimes B$. You can check that this works.
